# html textarea via python using post function

Tags: python, post, textarea

```
        <div><textarea cols="25" rows="12" name="box" id="box" tabindex="2">TEXT GOES HERE </textarea>

     </div>

    <div>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button-primary" value="Submi" tabindex="2"  /></p>      </div>
</form>
```

How can I fill the text area with my text from python code using post function?
I've been trying this way, but it just wont work! :S
br = { 'box' : "NEW text"}

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the form is displayed in a block of python code on the page, in which case you could use string formatting operations (python 2.6 or newer) to add in the value at the desired location:

```
print """
<div><textarea cols="25" rows="12" name="box" id="box" tabindex="2">{0!s} </textarea>""".format( text_variable )
```

Some web hosts still use python 2.5, in which case you'll need to use an older syntax style:

```
print """ My text says: %s """ % text_variable
```

If you are doing this to display arbitrary user input, be sure to pre-process your string in some way to avoid the insertion of arbitrary HTML code in the middle of your form.

In order to set *text_variable*, you'll want to get the form data. Look at the python "cgi" module and relevant [tutorials](http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/cgi/%22tutorial%22).

Comment: Hi abought, thank you fro replying to my question! I want to send text from python code into that box, another text , if u are understanding me ? ..

Comment: It really depends on how your HTML form is structured. (like, is it an HTML file or a python script? Is this taking the results of a POST operation to create a new form, or are you writing data for the first time? Etc.) The above code would allow you to write a python script that creates the form, and includes the specified python variable wherever you want inside the code for the textbox.