# Set text to html text area using python

Tags: python, html

I want to get user entered text,process it and then show it in html text area.The text is in English language. Currently what i'm getting is some gibberish html tags as the out put.
If i used an English string other than the Sinhalese string this works fine.
this is what i tried so far

```
cgitb.enable() #for debugging  
form = cgi.FieldStorage()  
doc1 = form.getvalue('doc1')
doc2 = form.getvalue('doc2')
sinstopwords = set(stopwords.words("sinhala"))
p = re.compile('[0-9]{1,9}')
p1 = re.compile('[0-9]{1,9}.[0-9]{1,9}')

data1 = doc1.replace('-','')
data2 = doc2.replace('-','')

newdata1 = p1.sub('0', p.sub('0',data1))
words1 = word_tokenize(newdata1)
newdata2 = p1.sub('0', p.sub('0',data2))
words2 = word_tokenize(newdata2)

filtered_sentence1 = [w1 for w1 in words1 if not w1 in sinstopwords]
filtered_sentence2 = [w2 for w2 in words2 if not w2 in sinstopwords]

outtext1 = ''
outtext2 = ''
for i in filtered_sentence1:
    outtext1 = outtext1 + i + ' '

for j in filtered_sentence2:
    outtext2 = outtext2 + j + ' '
```

Here is how i set the output in python using print()

```
print("""<textarea class="form-control" rows="20" name="doc1">""")
print(outtext1)
print("""</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Document 2</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" name="doc2">
""")
print(outtext2)
print("""</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Token length of doc1 before removing stopwords</label>
""")
```

This seems like some conversion problem but i don't have any idea to correct this.

Comment: Can you show an example of the "gibberish" output and the "real output"?

Comment: How do you deploy this? Does this also happen if you try it out locally in your terminal?

Comment: gibberish output - `<!--: spam
Content-Type: text/html

<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> -->
<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> --> -->
</font> </font> </font> </script> </object> </blockquote> </pre>
</table> </table> </table> </table> </table> </font> </font> </font>`

Comment: what i want to see is 'කෙසේ හෝ උදෑසන 10ට පමණ අප පන්සල් භූමියෙන් පිටත්ව උමා ඔය මාර්ගය අසලට පැමිණියේ වතුර බෝතල් 2ක් හා කැමරාව පමණක් අතැතිවය. මෙම ගමනේ අතිශය දුෂ්කර ජීවිත අවදානම පිරුණු කඳු නැගීම් තිබෙන අතර ඒ සඳහා කිසිදු කඹයක්වත් නොමැතිව' something like this in Sinhala. im deploying this in lamp locally. @syntonym

Comment: @abought I saw your answer on this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808852/html-textarea-via-python-using-post-function) there you have mentioned "If you are doing this to display arbitrary user input, be sure to pre-process your string in some way to avoid the insertion of arbitrary HTML code in the middle of your form."
I think that this is the problem in my case.Can you provide me some example how to pre process the input text because it seems there happens to be some arbitrary html code in my output.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if that is really what is happening. But you can try by `cgi.escape`.